# assemblies not being included when deploying Azure webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have 3 files

`MyWebJob.exe
MyClassLibraryProject.dll 
3rdPartyLib.dll (vc++)`

I zipped them and uploded it to web job, but I got error below.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyClassLibraryProject.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

How to fix it , thanks!

Comment: Where do you get that error - is it your code throwing it or the webjobs platform? Did you include all the dependencies the 3rd party library?

Comment: The error is from webjobs logs. Yes, I include all the 3rd party library files.